# Create multi touch button item in qml

Tags: android, qt, touch, qml

I am trying to write android program using qml that need to be multi touch in button press event. I used mouse area but it just give 1 touch in moment. I use MultiPointTouchArea tool but it can just give my touch points in a list and not effect on mouse area press event.
Actually in simple case i want two button (from one button object) in my application be touchable together.
thanks

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry that I do not have expertise on Android, but I hope this might help even with Android. It should do so, if QML is true to it's promise of platfrom independency.

```
Button {
    checkable: true
    checked: tp1.pressed
    MultiPointTouchArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        touchPoints: TouchPoint { id: tp1 }
    }
}
Button {
    x: 100
    checkable: true
    checked: tp2.pressed
    MultiPointTouchArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        touchPoints: TouchPoint { id: tp2 }
    }
}
```

Greetings,
-m-

Comment: Stumbed upon this question. What's the point of this answer? You should use just *one* `MultiPointTouchArea` to get the multitouch behaviour. That said Qt 5.9 should have support for multitouch in the newer release of multitouch.

Comment: To quote the documentation: "While a MultiPointTouchArea can take exclusive ownership of certain touch points, it is also possible to have multiple MultiPointTouchAreas active at the same time, each operating on a different set of touch points." This has adventages e.g. when you have multiple independent components, that require multitouch-functionality. Of course, you can use one `MultiPointTouchArea`, and then use somthing like itemAt(x,y) to find the child, that might want to handle it, but why?

Comment: I don't think it is going to work like that in Android. To tell you the truth, I don't think the documentation is correct in that part. Anyhow you can use dynamic points which are quite cool.

Comment: I think I tried it on a *Windows 10-Device with MultiTouch* and it worked. I will try it again, when I get my hands on it again.

Comment: I see. I don't think it work on Android. Or at least I think so but it would be interesting to give it a try. :) It's been a lot of time since I've first used the type on Android. I've free form rulers in a app of mine and had a very bad time with `MultiPointTouchArea` a `Flickable`s. Jeez!